# Android sticker imageview add left/right/top/bottom scale Arrow

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, scale

I have implemented Sticker Image-view Lib and it's work perfect with scale zoom delete but i want to scale Left/bottom/top/right specifically touched area of image will be scale And that left side touch will be only left scale will be scale only left right and top touch will be sale top/bottom.

What i have used for that is
https://github.com/kencheung4/android-StickerView
this library i have used.

What if i want to add four new action top/bottom/left/right action for that sticker-view.

my on-touch method is

```
private OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        if(view.getTag().equals("DraggableViewGroup")) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.v(TAG, "sticker view action down");
                    move_orgX = event.getRawX();
                    move_orgY = event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.v(TAG, "sticker view action move");
                    float offsetX = event.getRawX() - move_orgX;
                    float offsetY = event.getRawY() - move_orgY;
                    StickerView.this.setX(StickerView.this.getX()+offsetX);
                    StickerView.this.setY(StickerView.this.getY() + offsetY);
                    move_orgX = event.getRawX();
                    move_orgY = event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.v(TAG, "sticker view action up");
                    break;
            }
        }else if(view.getTag().equals("iv_scale")){
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.v(TAG, "iv_scale action down");

                    this_orgX = StickerView.this.getX();
                    this_orgY = StickerView.this.getY();

                    scale_orgX = event.getRawX();
                    scale_orgY = event.getRawY();
                    scale_orgWidth = StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().width;
                    scale_orgHeight = StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().height;

                    rotate_orgX = event.getRawX();
                    rotate_orgY = event.getRawY();

                    centerX = StickerView.this.getX()+
                            ((View)StickerView.this.getParent()).getX()+
                            (float)StickerView.this.getWidth()/2;


                    //double statusBarHeight = Math.ceil(25 * getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
                    int result = 0;
                    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
                    if (resourceId > 0) {
                        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
                    }
                    double statusBarHeight = result;
                    centerY = StickerView.this.getY()+
                            ((View)StickerView.this.getParent()).getY()+
                            statusBarHeight+
                            (float)StickerView.this.getHeight()/2;

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.v(TAG, "iv_scale action move");

                    rotate_newX = event.getRawX();
                    rotate_newY = event.getRawY();

                    double angle_diff = Math.abs(
                            Math.atan2(event.getRawY() - scale_orgY , event.getRawX() - scale_orgX)
                                    - Math.atan2(scale_orgY - centerY, scale_orgX - centerX))*180/Math.PI;

                    Log.v(TAG, "angle_diff: "+angle_diff);

                    double length1 = getLength(centerX, centerY, scale_orgX, scale_orgY);
                    double length2 = getLength(centerX, centerY, event.getRawX(), event.getRawY());

                    int size = convertDpToPixel(SELF_SIZE_DP, getContext());
                    if(length2 > length1
                            && (angle_diff < 25 || Math.abs(angle_diff-180)<25)
                            ) {
                        //scale up
                        double offsetX = Math.abs(event.getRawX() - scale_orgX);
                        double offsetY = Math.abs(event.getRawY() - scale_orgY);
                        double offset = Math.max(offsetX, offsetY);
                        offset = Math.round(offset);
                        StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().width += offset;
                        StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().height += offset;
                        onScaling(true);
                        //DraggableViewGroup.this.setX((float) (getX() - offset / 2));
                        //DraggableViewGroup.this.setY((float) (getY() - offset / 2));
                    }else if(length2 < length1
                            && (angle_diff < 25 || Math.abs(angle_diff-180)<25)
                            && StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().width > size/2
                            && StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().height > size/2) {
                        //scale down
                        double offsetX = Math.abs(event.getRawX() - scale_orgX);
                        double offsetY = Math.abs(event.getRawY() - scale_orgY);
                        double offset = Math.max(offsetX, offsetY);
                        offset = Math.round(offset);
                        StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().width -= offset;
                        StickerView.this.getLayoutParams().height -= offset;
                        onScaling(false);
                    }

                    //rotate

                    double angle = Math.atan2(event.getRawY() - centerY, event.getRawX() - centerX) * 180 / Math.PI;
                    Log.v(TAG, "log angle: " + angle);

                    //setRotation((float) angle - 45);
                    setRotation((float) angle - 45);
                    Log.v(TAG, "getRotation(): " + getRotation());

                    onRotating();

                    rotate_orgX = rotate_newX;
                    rotate_orgY = rotate_newY;

                    scale_orgX = event.getRawX();
                    scale_orgY = event.getRawY();

                    postInvalidate();
                    requestLayout();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.v(TAG, "iv_scale action up");
                    break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

is there any one who can help me for that...?

Comment: did you achieve to do it from all 4 sides?

Comment: Yes now its working perfect @Shrikant

Comment: Can you share the updated code?

Comment: @Shrikant are you got any solution?

Comment: @MasterWayne can you share your logic?